# What's the best way to combine Cassandra counters and Solr indexes in DSE

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

According to [DSE documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchUnsupported.html), DSE Search does not support counter columns.

I have a basic CF with (ckey, count), where `count` is the counter.

```
create table change_count ( ckey text, count counter) primary key (ckey)
```

Naturally, `dsetool create_core ks.change_count` fails on this CF, because there is a counter, with "Solr indexes are not supported on counters!" error.

OK, so I create the Solr schema document manually:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
   <types>
      <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField" />
   </types>
   <fields>
      <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="ckey" stored="true" type="StrField" />
   </fields>
   <uniqueKey>(ckey)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

, save it in a file, and use `dsetool create_core ks.change_count schema=/tmp/1.xml`, but I still get the same "Solr indexes are not supported on counters!" error.

So, the first question is - is there a way to strongarm DSE and have a CF with a counter, and solr indexes on columns that are not counters.

If it's not possible, then I'd like to have any suggestions on how to solve the problem of representing the data. Let's say 'ckey' is "epoch hour", and count is just a counter of some events that happened during that hour. The counter type for atomic increments, contention on this CF will be very high even if I used lightweight transactions. The Solr index is there because I want to do range searches and so on.

I can create 2 CFs:

```
create table change_count ( ckey text, count counter) primary key (ckey)
create table change_count_idx ( ckey text ) primary key (ckey)
```

I can then Solr-index `change_count_idx`, but count in `change_count` table, making sure that I have the same keys in both. Then I can get the matching keys using Solr, and actual data using Cassandra - doing the client-side join. But that can potentially be thousands of PK lookups, and I don't think the performance is going to survive large ranges.

Comment: In a table with counter columns, all *non-counter* columns must be part of the primary key.

Comment: This is not meant to be an answer to your question on a solution level, so I've moved it here. It's just a reminder for readers. The check in DSE is against the table's metadata, and assumes you don't want to index just the primary key.

Comment: @CalebRackliffe But I might want to index just my primary key, and use Solr to do crazy queries that are otherwise not supported in Cassandra. That's the idea behind this particular table.

Comment: If all you want to do is lookups against the primary key, I'm not sure why you would need Solr in the first place. Perhaps I missed something in my reading...

Comment: @CalebRackliffe I don't want to do lookups (which is the only thing Cassandra supports on PK), I want to do range queries, non-exact queries, etc.

Comment: Understood. In that case, a separate table is probably the best you can do for now. Cassandra 2.1 (and I think 3.0) don't even support standard secondary indexes on counter tables. You may be able to simplify your insertions with a trigger that adds a mutations for your change_count_idx table.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing isn't strictly possible with DSE Search.

It might be brittle, but if you actually want to search those counters, you may want to consider creating a "mirrored" version of `change_count` that uses `bigint` in place of `counter`. Then, you can periodically read the data from `change_count` into the "mirrored" table and query directly against that.